# Updating LDAP encrypted password via JNDI

Tags: java, ldap, jndi, des, crypt

I need some pointers how to update an encrypted password in an LDAP (OpenLDAP) of a user within an LDAP tree. The passwords in the LDAP server are prefixed with {crypt} which I suppose indicates that it is encrypted (with DES?)

I need to write a method which updates a user's passwords. What is the right way to do this? Do I need to prefix the string with {crypt} myself? How do I encrypt the password for {crypt}?

UPDATE:

Just to clarify what I need is the Java code to encrypt the attribute so that it works with {crypt}. I also don't know if I have to prefix the attribute with the string {crypt} myself.

Comment: Got the same problem with {SSHA}, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42490862/5428477), fixed it for me with salted SHA. If one changes the message digest algo an possibly drop the salt, I guess it will work for {CRYPT} as well.

Answer (score 1):

No, you just need to update the attribute, just like any other attribute, but remembering that unlike most attributes it is a byte[] not a String.

There is also an ExtendedOperation for password modification in association with the Password Policy IETF draft, but you haven't mentioned you're using that.

Comment: If I update the attribute it is stored clear text not encrypted. How do I get it to be encrypted?

Comment: It should be stored the same way it is currently stored at the server. You might have to add ;binary to the attribute name. I'm away from my source code right now but I'll have another look at this tomorrow.

Comment: I don't think you understood the question. I am asking how to encrypt the string before saving the attribute.

Comment: @jbx I understood all right, I have code that does this, and it doesn't encrypt anything. Nor does it prefix {crypt} itself. My understanding is that the JNDI layer takes care of that for you. All it does is attrs.put("userPassword", newPassword1.getBytes()); My understanding is also that if the attribute is appropriately defined either the JNDI layer or the server itself does the encrypting. Mine certainly does.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm still not really convinced its so. One can even have different encryptions (MD5, SHA1 etc.) apart from CRYPT, so I doubt that OpenLDAP does it automatically. If the encryption is not done client side, you would also risk passing the password unencrypted over the network. I also found this which seems to point towards this hypothesis http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2639167/how-to-specify-hash-algorithm-when-updating-ldap-via-java. So I just need to know how to generate a CRYPT password.

Comment: @jbx It is certain that between JNDI and OpenLDAP *someone* is doing it automatically, because someone is encrypting passwords and it certainly isn't anything in my code.

Comment: I am speaking of the userPassword attribute.

Comment: @jbx and my next question is why are you using {crypt} at all? See openldap.org/faq/data/cache/348.html. Not recommended. I can assure you that {MD5} passwords don't get transmitted in clear. I just sniffed it. And I have *no code* for hashing them.

Comment: @EJP well I am just using {crypt} because 60,000 entries in the LDAP server are using {crypt} and I just want to avoid introducing other unknowns.

Comment: @jbx good reason! Point remains though, JNDI clearly does it in the case of {SHA1}. I suggest you sniff the traffic.

Answer (score 0):

In some cases, using a pre-encoded password might prevent the directory server from enforcing password quality checks.